# Can a cheap cable prevent AC charging from working?

Tags: charging, sony-xperia-neo-v

A while ago, I had my phone repaired (the USB socket was worn out) and had to replace the USB cable as well. Since then I haven't been able to quickly charge my phone in AC mode. Previously it worked both on the dedicated charger that came with my phone and the "power" usb socket on my laptop. Is it plausible that this is because of the cheap cable?

My phone is a Sony Xperia Neo V.

Comment: Theoretically it could be the case. AFAIK the device distinguishes between its power source (USB or A/C) by a signal on a certain pin. So if that special "connection" is missing (or broken), the device might always think it's charging via USB. I'd recommend to go to some shop/repair station and try another cable.

Comment: AFAIR the "signal" is that the data pins are shorted. That can't possibly the way my notebook signaled this as the data transfers and AC charging used to work at the same time just fine.

Comment: I found no reference for the PIN assignment so far (didn't dig that deep, admittedly). So we both are just *guessing*. But regardless of that (which might take a while to be discussed) -- simply go and check with a different cable will answer your original question promptly. Of course, if you prefer, you might wait out here for a final answer, Santa Claus is near ;) (sorry, couldn't resist)

Answer (score 1):

It is quite possible that the "cheap" cable is a culprit. You could try a couple of things

- Replace the cable with a cable of 24/28 awg thickness. Google for "28/24 awg micro USB" to locate suppliers close by. These cables are thick and offer less resistance to charging current. Alternatively, if you have a spare thick cable of shorter length you could try that and see if the charging is faster.
- Download [Ampere](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gombosdev.ampere), It measures the charging current (it does not work on all devices, but your device is NOT mentioned in exclusion list, so it should work). Connect the "cheap cable" on charge and measure the  charging current. Repeat with cable you purchased (24/28 awg) or a spare short thick cable. If the value in second case is higher, the conclusion is obvious. You could even try compare values an  with OEM cable if you can locate with a friend or at a service center.
- You could consider buying an original Sony cable . I found one on [eBay](http://m.ebay.in/itm/221363204504?_mwBanner=1) costing about $5.

Comment: Much after this answer a detailed answer on this had been posted  by me [how-to-choose-micro-usb-cable-for-my-device](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/192/how-to-choose-micro-usb-cable-for-my-device/134970#134970)