# Which charging cable should I use? Short or long, and why?

Tags: charging, rca-voyager-ii

I have a 7" Android RCA VoyagerII tablet.  The instructions say I must use the very short cord charger that came with it and not even try anything else.  Is this true or can I use a regular long corded phone wall charger that matches the connector?

Answer (score 2):

Why the OEM is advising you is to use the charging cable that was supplied since

1. Shorter cables are normally thicker and offer less resistance
2. Impedance of the cable is matched to the charger

On the other hand, longer cables are generally thinner and offer more resistance for charging current and takes longer to charge, besides the  impedance mis-match at phone and charger ends for charging to happen as rated.

You can measure the current output of OEM cable using apps like [Ampere](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gombosdev.ampere) and [3C Battery Monitoring Widget](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gombosdev.ampere)

Do stick with OEM recommendations, unless you find a long cable that matches same performance as cable supplied.

**Edit:** For a detailed explanation which answers "why short cables are better and how to select a USB cable", see my answer [How to choose micro USB cable for my device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/134970/131553). I believe that would fully equip you in making a right choice

Comment: Generally a good cable to go with is a 24/28awg rated Micro Usb. I have had very good success with these on a variety of devices.