# Repairing a suddenly dead Samsung Galaxy Note Pro 12.2

Tags: hardware, samsung-galaxy-note-10.1

Samsung Galaxy Note Pro [12.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_Note_Pro_12.2)
([1](https://www.samsung.com/uk/tablets/galaxy-note-pro-12-2-p900/SM-P9000ZKABTU/),
[2](https://www.samsung.com/latin_en/business/tablets/galaxy-note-pro-12-2-p900/sm-p9000zkltpa/))
bought used for diversity of Android tests during app development. Died suddenly a year later.

Would still like to keep it running. It now has no sign of life when plugged in, but
because the battery was still holding a 3-hour charge when last used, I suspect that the sudden death is
not caused by the battery. The battery would have dwindled more slowly.

1. Net [chatter](https://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-note-pro-12-2/693393-best-battery-replacement-model-samsung-galaxy-note-pro-12-2-sm-p901.html) suggests that the USB connector is prone to breaking. Have you been there? Is this repairable?
2. I am content to use it with the power cord attached. Yet replacement battery sellers suggest that presence of a working battery is necessary. Have you been there? Can you confirm one way or the other?

I used the 10.1 tag because the 12.2 is identical in build quality (or lack thereof) to the 10.1. Your experience with the Samsung Galaxy Note pro 10.1 is likely very relevant.

Comment: afaik you need a real DC current (not just a pulsed DC from AC-DC Power Supply) best stable solution is always battery

Comment: @alecxs Interesting. So the device is sold with a modest adapter, and the battery acts as a super-large capacitor? Does this happen often?

Comment: battery is not used as capacitor. but simplyfied, yes it's a common design to use power supply just for charging purposes, while the current is taken from battery only. buy this maybe it is sufficient for your needs https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32858352800.html

Comment: maybe interesting too: some batteries can be boosted by heating a little. once you get it above ~2.2 volts the device should start charging again https://android.stackexchange.com/a/145155

Comment: @alecxs That's new. I'm assuming heating up to maybe 60C, not much more. What's a safe way to do it? More importantly, Could the battery have died suddenly? Doesn't sudden death mean that something else failed?

Comment: safe way is put it in the sun :) i have no clue, but worth a try. maybe the android battery stats was wrong and lied to you, because it was recognizing voltage on data pins 2+3 but the charging voltage on pin 1 was in fact missing or weak current. but that's just rather far-fetched