# Force Android to get the most out of a power bank

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, battery, samsung-galaxy-a3

In a sad case of "two smarts make for a stupid", my powerbank is trying to adjust to the power needed by my Galaxy A3, while the phone, probably trying to do the same, settles for a low amperage.  As a result, the battery charges at 500 mA instead of 1500.  Is there a way I can force my phone to suck faster from the powerbank?

*Notes:*

1. A Galaxy S4 does get 1500 mA from the power bank;
2. The Galaxy A3 does charge at 1500 mA when plugged to a charger.
3. The powerbank is a GP Powerbank FP05M 3.7V 5000 mAh/18.5Wh, Input DC 5V/2A; output DC 5V/2.1A.

Comment: This is not uncommon unfortunately... Try a different cable or port on the brick

Comment: What is your power bank output rating? Can you add specs to the question please ?

Comment: @acejavelin: Thanks!  So it's not the cable's fault (it works with other devices) and there's only 1 output port on the power bank.

Comment: Power bank specs are fine, it ought to charge at a higher rate. While you have ruled out the cable, it can make a significant difference. Try using a thicker shorter cable see my [Answer here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/134970/131553)

Comment: @beeshyams: Thanks for your input.  All the cables I use do 1500 mA quite fine with a USB plug that is directly plug to an outlet.  I tried three different cables of different thicknesses with the same result.

Comment: Well, I am out of options and wish as much to understand what's happening here! All the best :)