# Do I need specific cable for fast charging Samsung Galaxy S6?

Tags: charging, samsung-galaxy-s-6

My Samsung Galaxy S6 fast charging cable has broken and I was wondering whether I needed to buy a cable specifically for fast charging, or just a regular media cable.

The fast charging plug socket isn't broken, it's just the cable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fast charging is not related to the cable - the circuitry is in the adapter and device. That said you need to buy a cable that can carry higher amperage , allowing fast charging speed ( cable per se doesn't increase the speed but because it permits more power, speed is increased)

Thicker the cable, better it is ( thicker cables have lower AWG number )

Go in for a cable like 
[Tronsmart cables](http://www.amazon.in/Tronsmart-Compatible-Charging-transfer-Motorolla/dp/B01CCQHGUG?ie=UTF8&psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00) at a price comparable with budget cables. These are 20 AWG thickness for charging (provide best charging) 28 AWG for data (thinner thickness doesn't affect data transfer speeds)

For technical details of a good quality cable see my answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/134970/131553)

I am not affiliated with the product- a very satisfied user

Comment: Thanks for replying. So will the amperage affect the charging speed?

Comment: Yes. If cable can't  support higher amperage, speed is decreased.  If the answer meets your expectations, you may accept it by clicking the green Arrow next to up / form votes

Answer (score 2):

You'll want a quality cable, but the important part is the fast charging adapter itself, and if that's not broken or anything then you should be able to use any good quality cable.