# How can I get a longer Samsung USB data cable for Galaxy S4?

Tags: usb, samsung-galaxy-s-4

I have tried several alternate and extension USB cables and none of them provide a data connection. They were all new cables that worked just fine with standard external USB drives. Only the originally provided Samsung OEM white cable provides a data connection.

I have no interest in charging.

It would appear that there is something Samsung-specific in the physical design of this cable that allows the device to sense this and refuse to start a data connection.

Is there any way to obtain a longer cable with this same characteristic. Either an entirely separate cable or an extension cable. Obviously this is for the purpose of connecting my phone via a longer USB cable and being able to transfer files.

**Please do not respond with any speculation.** I am only interested in answers that propose solutions that **specifically handle this Samsung-specific "feature"**.

I don't consider Amazon(or similar) shop listings that just happen to list the model name in the description as being even slightly trustworthy (based on experience buying a few!). Lots of sellers just spam the listing with every common model name.

My phone's specs are

- model = GT-I9505
- OS = 5.0.1

Also please note that I am not using a separate charger. The phone is always plugged into the same USB port of a Win10 desktop PC. It seems to charge fine but i honestly don't pay it much attention to exactly how fast it charges.

Thanks!

update

Based on clues provided by @beeshyams.
the S4 cables are modified to provide higher charge to maximize efficient charging. Lack of support for this feature in a cable may cause the S4 to refuse a data connection. note that the S4 still charges with the "inferior" cable it just charges more slowly.

Comment: thanks @beeshyams , but those kinds of products listings are basically spam in my experience. Question updated as you suggested.

Comment: @beeshyams that's exactly my intent. I've read a mountain of vague info but no one seems to know the actual facts. I want hard evidence from someone who really knows whats going on with this annoying cable. It cannot be that hard for someone to electrically reverse-engineer it (unless there is a tiny chip embedded in it!).

Comment: For realz though, I've never heard of any Samsung devices around me being picky about cables. I also have/had several Samsung devices, and although I do flash them with custom ROMs, before flashing I have to transfer data from/to them, and generic cables I bought (I got several LG ones for their high current capabilities) work just fine.

Comment: @beeshyams , I don't understand exactly what you are proposing to do. I'm very happy to DIY in general but don't have electronics tools/workbench. I also don't want to waste your time!

Comment: For realz i have 2 OEM cables that always work and tried about a dozen that never work on my phone. I have read vague hints from people about different wiring in some cables but they are usually focused on the charging aspect of things, not the data connection. SOMEONE must know for sure ????

Comment: can you please join me [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62084/discussion-between-beeshyams-and-xavier-fakerat)

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding of the multiple posts on Internet dealing with charging of S4 :

- The Charging adapter has it's D+ and D- pins shorted with resistors across them. This is done  to ensure that higher current does not flow , reducing chances of damages to the device (see Fizz's [answer on electrical.SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/191983/90246) and [this XDA post](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2274321)
- This is NOT non standard but less frequently implemented (Apple legacy continued with few Android OEM's )
- This affects (or should ) *charging only*
- USB cables should not have anything to do with data transfer when connected to a PC . The only reasons I can think why this is happening are :

  1. Non OEM cables purchased may be poor in shielding - XDA post linked above mentions this , though on context of charging ( I am not entirely sure how much it could affect )
  2. They happen to be all [Power only no data aka USB condom cables](https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=UKbuVsfAA8qJ8QeDirfwCw#q=power+only+usb+cable)

Both possibilities are debatable

To eliminate the possibility of shielding affecting , suggest you to consider the cables mentioned in my [answer here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/134970/131553) . They are very sturdy and 2M long and give excellent charging performance too ( I am not canvassing for them - totally satisfied customer )

3. USB cables of Samsung are also modified in some way , and this prevents other USB cables from transferring data - this is more likely but haven't come across any solid evidence to support and will update if I do find something

Comment: thanks @beeshyams for the specific detail. I at least have a direction to research further now. I'd be happy to accept your answer if nothing better comes up after leaving it open for several days.

Comment: Would be following this -starred it. All the best

Comment: Wondering if you could find the cause ?