# Moto G5 Plus: Can you use a different USB cable (with the original charger) for charging?

Tags: charging

I know using a different adapter than the original one can cause problems later on, but is that the same for charging (USB) cables?

This guy [here says it's fine](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Moto-G5-Moto-G5-Plus/From-where-i-can-buy-the-New-usb-cable-for-my-moto-g5-plus/td-p/3739163)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- It's perfectly fine as long as the cable supports charging and not data only
- For help on choosing non OEM cable see my answer here [How to choose micro USB cable for my device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/192/131553)
- My wife has the same device and it works perfectly fine with cable recommended above (or any other cable that supports charging)

**Edit:** If you are wondering if they support *turbo charging* - yes they do. Verified on my previous device Moto X Play and my wife's G5plus. Search for cables that support fast charging as they are usually thicker and more efficient

Comment: Edited to add more detail about Turbo charging

Comment: Did you try as suggested?

Answer (score 1):

You can use any kind of good data cables (good means original ones made by a registered manufacturer), but make sure those cables are not bought by roadside vendors or a product of local Chinese manufacturer. 
As **Chinese** data cables are very low rate of data transfer and they really don't prevent from **shocks** or electrical glitch, that can seriously damage your phone.

You can also use **different** **Adapters** for **charging** your phone, but make sure that the **Input** and **Output** parameters (mA or Amp) are same as yours. As phones are made for specific Input **Amps**.