# Is it safe to charge tablet from phone via OTG cable if tablet's adapter is 5.2V?

Tags: charging, tablet, usb-on-the-go

Is it safe to charge tablet from phone via OTG cable if tablet's adapter is 5.2V (a bit above)?

Comment: Your question does not make sense to me. Charging one device from another only works if both devices use USB-C and the power providing device supports USB power delivery. For USB-C there is no such thing as an OTG cable, just us an USB-C to USB-C cable with USB-PD support. And why you mention the tablet (charging) adapter is totally unclear to me as it is not relevant at all.

Comment: "Charging one device from another only works if both devices use USB-C" - thanks, didn't know that. I ordered LG V20 with extended battery and I have Lenovo Tab 10. As musician, I have a lot of screen on time because I use tablet as sheet music. So I want to be able to charge my tablet from LG V20 extended battery.

Comment: The LGv20 has a 3200 mAh battery and the Tab 10 one with 7000mAh. Charging the large battery using a much smaller one is not very effective. May be you should better look for a power bank.

Comment: I ordered [this](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32919121802.html) extended battery and I want to carry less things.

Comment: IDK maybe I need to cancel it and find phone with micro-usb type B

Comment: I just tried to charge my mom's C-Type Xiaomi Redmi Note 7 from Tablet and it works, why do you say it's not working? And C-Type OTG cable [exists](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ACYBGNRcUAmHe0r9PmpWMhHBwXXvMuz30g%3A1576696436225&ei=dHr6XaaoDcGsaZiniJAJ&q=otg+cable+type+c&oq=otg+cable+type+c&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i203l4j0i22i30l6.616.2414..2851...0.0..0.284.2197.0j11j2......0....1..gws-wiz.......35i39i19j0i7i30j0i22i10i30.FVpLWUlERa0&ved=0ahUKEwimsv_387_mAhVBVhoKHZgTApIQ4dUDCAs&uact=5)

Comment: The cable you have linked to is just a plain USB-C male to USB-A female cable. OTG is specific to micro USB ports (one special pin is used to identify if a cable is an regular or an OTG cable). For USB-C there are no such thing like an OTG cable. You can just use regular adapter cables and it works as you already have found out.

Comment: Is this [cable](https://www.oneplus.com/lt/product/oneplus-type-c-otg-cable) fake? Because it says OTG. If yes, will mouse, keyboard and etc. still work with phone that supports OTG using this cable?

Comment: No it is not a fake - OTG of USB-C is just marketing nonsense. With USB-C there are no OTG cables anymore - or if you look at it from the other side every USB-C cable with an male USB-C plug and 
 a female connector at the other end can be considered an OTG cable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes**, as long as it is supported by the tablet and you have compatible cables available.

[USB Standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB) specify that charging voltage should be 5.00V ± 0.25V, i.e. 4.75V~5.25V.

Upper limit is 5.25V which is higher than tablet adapter voltage ; add to this the resistance offered by the cable and the input voltage will be well within safety limits.

How efficient it would be is upto you to verify as [Robert pointed out in comments](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/219525/is-it-safe-to-charge-tablet-from-phone-via-otg-cable-if-tablets-adapter-is-5-2v#comment282989_219525)

Comment: Thank you for answer! Another thing: if I charge like that, will I lose almost 50% of energy. Because when energy goes from battery to cable it loses ~25% and after that when goes to another battery will I lose another ~25%?

Comment: Cable losses are not so high as you suspect. You can buy a good cable. For help see this [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/134970/131553).  How much over all loss you would have needs to be tested by you. That said, power bank is a better option as suggested by Robert

Comment: I don't really understand why power bank is better option if I will have 10500mAh battery for my phone. Anyway, is loss by charging using phone will be higher than using powerbank?

Comment: From your answer I understand that cable thickness matters.

Comment: yes............

Comment: Is it possible to know AWG of my current cables?

Comment: So, if I want to use 1A charger without more loss than USB standards and with transfering function, it has to be 15cm long (AWG 28)?

Comment: Sorry,busy so can't verify what you are claiming but please re-read and if you still have a question ask a separate question linking that answer as background. you can know the AWG either through documentation or physical measurement or ask somebody who deals in cables

Comment: Ok, thanks for help.

Comment: Simply put go in for long, thick cable. Sample link is provided in that answer